# Converting IP address into bytes in python

Tags: python, ip

Say i have an IP address in python

```
addr = '164.107.113.18'
```

How do i convert the IP address into 4 bytes?

Comment: What is your expected result? You have an extra period in your IP.

Comment: That was a syntax error on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with [Maciej Gol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33244838/1869370), but here's another way:

```
ip = '192.168.1.1'
ip_as_bytes = bytes(map(int, ip.split('.')))
```

**EDIT**: Oops, this is Python 3.X only. For Python 2.X

```
ip = '192.168.1.1'
ip_as_bytes = ''.join(map(chr,map(int,ip.split('.'))))
```

You're better off using the [socket module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33244838/1869370), however, given its efficiency:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("socket.inet_aton('164.107.113.18')",setup='import socket')
0.22455310821533203
>>> timeit.timeit("''.join(map(chr,map(int,'164.107.113.18'.split('.'))))")
3.8679449558258057
```

Answer (score 11):

Use [`socket.inet_aton`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.inet_aton):

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.inet_aton('164.107.113.18')
'\xa4kq\x12'
>>> socket.inet_aton('127.0.0.1')
'\x7f\x00\x00\x01'
```

This returns a byte-string (or `bytes` object on Python 3.x) that you can get bytes from. Alternatively, you can use `struct` to get each byte's integer value:

```
>>> import socket
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('BBBB', socket.inet_aton('164.107.113.18'))
(164, 107, 113, 18)
```

Comment: So does socket.inet_aton(addr) return a string of 4 characters?

Comment: For Python 2.x a `str` object is just a byte string, thus these 4 characters represent 4 bytes. For 3.x it returns a bytes object.