# Byte-encoding IP address in Python 3 and converting back to string

Tags: python-3.x, networking, udp, ip

I'm trying to create sample UDP packet headers in Python3 as such:

```
# "encoding"
header = bytearray()
ip = '192.168.1.1'
ip_bytes = bytes(map(int, ip.split('.')))
header.extend(ip_bytes)
port = 5555    
header.extend(port.to_bytes(2, 'big'))
print(header)
print()

# "decoding"
destip = header[:4]
ips = ""
for i in destip:
    byt = int.from_bytes(destip[i:i+1], 'big')
    ips += str(byt) + "."
ips = ips[:len(ips)-1]
print(ips)
```

And the output is:

```
bytearray(b'\xc0\xa8\x01\x01\x15\xb3')

bytearray(b'\xc0\xa8\x01\x01')
0.0.168.168
```

What I want is for the second line to be:

```
192.168.1.1
```

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting IP address into bytes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244775/converting-ip-address-into-bytes-in-python)

Comment: @thatrockbottomprogrammer What I'm struggling with is converting the ip BACK to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert the ip_arg string to an int, 19216811 is not the int you want to encode. 192.168.1.1 = 3232235777 as an int. You could do the reverse of what you're doing in the decode section and convert each octet.

Comment: SOLVED. The byte to int conversion in the decoding for loop should be: int.from_bytes([i], 'big')