# Is there any way to get some information with snmp without oids?

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp, snmp-trap

Im started to deal with snmp. I want to get some information from devices in my network like an ip address, mac address, name and etc. I want to do network discovery thing.
I have the code belwow. I dont want to use oid numbers for that informations. Is there any way to get the information without oids?
Also, the output is my code is wrong. characters not showing properly

**Code:**

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
import datetime

class SNMP_QUERY():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __del__(self):
        pass


def snmp_query(host, community, oid):
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
        getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
               CommunityData(community),
               UdpTransportTarget((host, 161)),
               ContextData(),
               ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)),
               lookupMib=False))

    if errorIndication:
        print(errorIndication)
    else:
        if errorStatus:
            print('%s at %s' % (
                errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1] or '?'
            )
                  )
        else:
            for name, val in varBinds:
                return (str(val))


def main():
    # Network Device
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    community = 'public'

    #overviewModelName = '.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0'
    name = '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0'
    macAddres = '.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.12'
    io_address = '.1.3.6.1.2.1.4.21.1.1.192.168.1.27'

    result = {}
   # result['Model Name'] = snmp_query(host, community, overviewModelName)
    result['Name'] = snmp_query(host, community, name)
    result['Mac Adress'] = snmp_query(host, community, macAddres)
    result['IP'] = snmp_query(host, community, io_address)

    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output::**

```
{'Name': 'DESKTOP-ANIHIT4', 'Mac Adress': 'ÜA©Hð&', 'IP': 'À¨\x01\x1b'}
```

Comment: Your output seems correct. The IP and MAC Address is not a string, but a series of bytes. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244775/converting-ip-address-into-bytes-in-python) on how to convert them to a human readable text.

Answer (score 0):

The entire SNMP stack is built upon OIDs, so it is impossible to go without them.

The output does not meet your expectation, because the actual data stored for certain OIDs (like the last two in your case) are encoded and not convertible to `str`. So the actual solution is to learn how they were encoded and decode the data properly.

That's not an easy task for SNMP beginners but good books can teach what `TEXT-CONVENTION` is and how it defines the encoding of complex object types (such as `MacAddress` https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmppro-mib/blob/master/SNMPv2-TC.txt#L92).